# Filling input forms with javascript (document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value="2") then submitting but sumbit not working

Tags: javascript, forms, input, submit, form-submit

I am a beginner and i encountered something on the web :

on a website, a form was pretty easy and i wanted to try doing something like filling the form's inputs like this :

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].value="2";}
```

visually, the form's inputs were actually filled. but when i click on the button after that, nothing happens.

When using the mouse and keyboard to fill the inputs, it works if no one is left empty. if at least one is left empty, nothing happens, which is the same result as with the javascript code.

In some other websites like Facebook and using the javascript code i can submit.

It bugged me so much and with my knowledge and i can only guess that there are many possibilities for the reason behind that, but i thought that maybe you would know more specifically what the reason was, like if it is something known.

EDIT : HTML FORM CODE

```
<form data-v-495bbcce="" class="el-form">
<div data-v-495bbcce="" class="codeInput">
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<div class="el-input">
<!---->
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" autofocus="autofocus" class="el-input__inner">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
</div>
<button data-v-495bbcce="" type="submit" class="el-button reservedPinDialog__button el-button--primary">
<!----><!---->
<span>Déverrouiller la réservation</span>
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you look at the Console to see if any errors were thrown?  Do you have a fiddle where we can see this not working?  Thanks!

Comment: paste HTML here

Comment: No Console Errors, form HTML in first post, thanks for your reply